# ASP.NET MVC - отключить/настроить jquery-валидацию input

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, валидация

Возможно, глупая ситуация, но я не смог найти решения.
Input добавляется во вьюшку вручную и никак не связан с моделью. Второй input для сравнения:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...

    <input id="1" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
}
<input id="2" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
```

При запуске (на странице):

```
<form action="/Calls/Create" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    ...   
    <input id="1" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
</form>
<input id="2" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
```

После ввода значений (на странице):

```
<form action="/Calls/Create" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    ...
    <input id="1" class="form-control input-validation-error" 
    type="text" value="" aria-describedby="1-error" aria-
    invalid="true">
</form>
<input id="2" class="form-control" type="text" value="">
```

Первому input, который в блоке формы, jquery прописывает дополнительные атрибуты, второй остается неизменным. Насколько я понимаю, работает jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js. Если ты написал что-то помимо цифр в первый input, то submit не проходит и ставит туда курсор. Собственно вопрос, как отключить данную валидацию, которая мне не нужна, либо как ее настроить? И в чем причина такого поведения?

Comment: попробуйте добавить `data-val='false'` атрибут к полю, или вызывать `Html.EnableClientValidation(false);` перед полем

Comment: Есть радикальное решение отключить jquery validation на странице, и оно работает, но хотелось бы знать, почему она ругается и каким образом указать параметры этой валидации.